# How does a computer determine the data type of a byte?

Tags: memory-hardware, memory-access, type-checking

For example, if the computer has `10111100` stored on one particular byte of RAM, how does the computer know to interpret this byte as an integer, ASCII character, or something else? Is type data stored in an adjacent byte? (I don't think this would be the case as this would result in using twice the amount of space for one byte.)

I suspect that perhaps a computer does not even know the type of data, that only the program using it knows. My guess is that because RAM is **R**AM and therefore not read sequentially, that a particular program just tells the CPU to fetch the info from a specific address and the program defines how to treat it. This would seem to fit with programming things such as the need for typecasting.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: As a side note: If you are talking about types you must do it in a language context. It's left to the compiler to handle that sort of thing (symbols, check types, operations, casting, address ram, etc). CPU and RAM only knows bytes

Comment: The data type of a byte is a byte.  Beyond that, the computer doesn't know anything.  A program might interpret a byte or a group of bytes as a particular data type, and attempt to perform operations on those, but there's no restrictions there.  The same group of bytes could be interpreted as more than one data type (i.e. casting pointers to value types, C-like unions, etc.).

That RAM is not read sequentially is not really relevant. -- It's more because RAM is general purpose. -- Registers for example are also not read sequentially, but they are typed.

Comment: Shameless plug for myself, but this question was basically asked over on the programmers SE about a month ago.  [Here's my answer to it](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/291957/103314).  It's kind of long at this point, but attacks it from several different angles.

Comment: One useful consequence of the fact that the hardware is datatype-agnostic is that a single byte (or word, etc.) can be interpreted multiple ways by a program.  Notably, temporarily interpreting a floating-point number as an integer is used to compute the [fast inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root).

Comment: @BrainSlugs83, might you consider converting that to an answer?

Comment: By the way, the binary value `10111100` is not an ASCII character. ASCII only goes up to `01111111`! It could be a character from another character set though...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct. The CPU doesn't care about the semantics of your data. Sometimes, though, it does make a difference. For example, some arithmetic operations produce different results when the arguments are semantically signed or unsigned. In that case you need to tell the CPU which interpretation you intended.

It is up to the programmer to make sense of her data. The CPU only obeys orders, blissfully unaware of their meaning or goals.

Comment: Regarding "when the arguments are semantically signed or unsigned", how would the CPU know? The CPU operations just see parameter bytes and lack that sort of data type context awareness. You imply the data type by choosing the appropriate CPU operation (or your compiler does).

Comment: @Shiv In such cases, the CPU is actually issued a different instruction to process signed numbers versus unsigned numbers.  As in the OP's suspicions, the program is obliged to provide those details, because the CPU is unaware.

Comment: I've been working with computers as long as I remember myself, and even though I know that CPU doesn't care about the high level constructs we use on high level programming, but this separation of concepts still freaks me out from time to time

Comment: @Loupax Well, working with a really low-level assembly helps quite a bit - even `mov al, 42` is kind of high-level - it's obvious there's only one possible instruction this could call, but it's still somewhat abstracted away. However, using `mov.8 al, 42` explicitly makes this painfully obvious :)

Comment: @Shiv: That's correct. What determines the data type is the instructions, not the data. You use a different instruction to add two signed integers vs two unsigned integers. On some architectures, it's not even that. Some machines only have 2's complement as the "number" type and no floating point type in hardware. On such machines, all calculations are done on the 2's complement integers and only when you want to print the result to screen would you decide weather to treat the number as signed or unsigned.

Comment: @Shiv: I'd like to note that there are machines where the data in memory are typed. These are called tagged memory architectures (or simply tagged architectures) but they've not been as successful commercially as regular architectures partly because we now program mostly in compiled languages instead of assembly and the compiler takes care of typing. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_architecture

Comment: @slebetman in 2's complement integers, adding and subtracting is the same operation whether signed or unsigned. But multiply, divide, and *comparisons* are not. You have to know not just when you display the resukts (which involves division to format as decimal) but when you test-and-branch.

Comment: @usr I don't think Itanium has anything of the sort. I do recall a flag for registers that have not been initialized, though.

Comment: That might be what it's called, but it's for registers only and indicates allocated and read before written; not whether it's an int or whatever.  However, different registers for floating point (as with other archetectures) is *sort of* a distinguishing method.

Comment: How do you *tell the CPU which interpretation you intended*? You don't. You construct a series of real computer instructions that emulate the required semantics, usually those of a particular programming language.

Comment: @Thumbnail You do it on an instruction by instruction basis. The x86 architecture has different arithmetic operations for signed and unsigned operands, and even MOV instructions with either zero extension or sign extension (for implementing type promotion).

Comment: So the CPU looks at the instructions, infers therefrom how to interpret it  (signed number, unsigned number, or whatever), and acts accordingly. No it doesn't. It will perform any nonsensical (to you and me) sequence of mixed signed/unsigned, fixed or floating, simple-word/array-access you give it. Except for tagged architectures (Burroughs B5500/6500 ...? AS400? Lisp-machines?) the CPU simply operates on flat data. Interpretation is in the eye of the programmer.

Comment: @Thumbnail "So the CPU looks at the instructions, infers therefrom how to interpret it (signed number, unsigned number, or whatever), and acts accordingly." Exactly. If you tell it that the operands are signed, it performs signed arithmetic, while if you tell it that the operands are unsigned, it performs unsigned arithmetic. You can then change your mind, and the CPU won't care. But when it executes each instruction, it does so according to the type information you provide.

Answer (score 14):

As others have already answered, today's common CPUs do not know what a given memory position contains; the software decides.

However, there are other possibilities. Lisp Machines for example used a [tagged architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_architecture) which stored the type of each memory position; that way the hardware itself could do some of the work of high-level languages.

And even now, I guess you could consider the [NX bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit) in Intel, AMD, ARM and other architectures to follow the same principle: distinguish at the hardware level whether a given memory zone contains data or instructions.

Also, just for completeness, in [Harvard architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) (like some microcontrollers) data and instructions are physically separated, so the CPU does have some idea of what it is reading.

In this [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-lisp-machine-and-what-is-so-great-about-them?share=1) there's some commentary on how the tagged memory worked, its performance implications and demise, and more.

Comment: Tagged architecture is an interesting note. Would it be significantly faster?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The program just gets a byte from the memory and it can interpret it however it wants.

Answer (score 3):

There are no type annotations.
RAM stores pure data, and then program defines what to do.

With CPU registers is a bit harder, if you have registers of given type (like FPU), you tell what is inside.
Operations on floating point registers are explicitly using typed data. You or your compiler tell what and when should be put there, so you not have such freedom.
Computer does not make any assumptions on underlying data in RAM, and in registers with one exception - typed registers in CPU are of known type, optimised to deal with it. This is only to show that there are places where data is to be of expected type, but nothing stops you from casting strings to floats and multiply them.

In programming languages you specify type, or in higher level languages data is general and compiler / interpreter / VM encodes what is inside with overhead.
For example in C your pointer type tells what to do with data, how to access it.

Of course you can read string (characters) and treat then as floating point values, integers and mix them.

Comment: Even bits in an FPU register don't always represent floating point values. In the old days (maybe not so much anymore?), a common optimization was to use floating point registers (64-bits or larger) to copy data faster than general purpose/integer registers (32-bit), being twice as big, they were generally able to copy data twice as fast.

Comment: I totally agree with you, that is why I wrote somebody might push strings there. And in the same times people did floating point operations on integers, because it was faster. That is the point!

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans there are instructions that manipulate floating-point values. If FADD is used it only makes sense that the (4,8,or 10)-byte groups of memory held floating-point numbers.  That's true for several kinds of instruction: multiply two integers only makes sense if they are integers, jump only makes sense if it's an address.

Comment: @seth and evilJS that's not assumed to be the case for legacy floating point stacked 8087 instructions, but is the case for newer CIMD registers which may be used just for loading/saving with no interpretation (though they must be aligned), and a caveat that if the CIMD registers were *never* used than they don't need to be saved in a context switch. If you (only) move 8 bytes via XMM register it's a net loss as the whole set needs to be saved.

Answer (score 3):

The CPU doesn't care, it executes assembly code, which justs merely moves data around, shift it, add it or multiply it...

Data Types are a higher level language concept: in C or C++ you need to specify Types for every single piece of data you manipulate; the C/C++ Compiler takes care of transforming these pieces of data into the right commands for the CPU to process (compilers write assembly code)

In some even higher level languages, Types may be inferred: in Python or Javascript, for example, one does not have to specify data types, yet data has a type and you can't add a string with an integer, but you can add a float with an integer: the 'compiler' (which in the case of Javascript is a JIT (Just in Time) Compiler. Javascript is often called an 'interpreted' language because historically browsers interpreted Javascript code, but nowadays Javascript engines are compilers.

Code, always ends up being compiled to machine code, but obviously machine code format depends on the machine you're targeting (x86 64bit code won't work on a x86 32 bits machine or a ARM processor for example)

So there is actually a lot of layers involved in running interpreted code.

Java and C# are other interesting ones, as Java or C# code is technically 'compiled' to a Java binary (bytecode), but that code itself is then interpreted by the Java Runtime, which is specific to the underlying hardware (one needs to install the JRE targeting the right machine to run Java binaries (Jars) )

Comment: A compiler compiles, be it JIT or not; and an interpreter interprets without compiling (because if not it would be a compiler!). They are very different things. And regarding "Java being funny" because of bytecode interpretation, consider that even x86 machine code will actually be interpreted (or even compiled?) by the very microprocessor into [microcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... Agreed: a compiler compiles, and an interpreter interprets. In the case of Javascript though the story is a bit complicated since some older browser interpret the code, while more modern browsers actually compile just-in-time, which is probably why it is still referred to as an 'interpreted' language even though it is technically not anymore.

Comment: But AFAIK, JS starts interpreted, and then might get compiled as needed. And JITs can switch from interpreted to compiled to interpreted again, depending on lots of things. For example, a piece of code might get compiled for a variable having a given type; but then the code is run again with that variable having a different type, so the existing compiled code can't be used so the interpreter jumps in - until the code gets compiled again for the new type...

Comment: You're citing me on something I didn't say, please remove it because it's totally wrong. Microcode has NOTHING to do with the OS; it's something internal to the microprocessor. 32 bit or 64 bit also has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

Datatypes are not a hardware feature. The CPU knows a couple (well, a lot) of
different commands. Those are called the *instruction set* of a CPU.

One of the
best known ones is the [x86 instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings).
If you search for "multiply" on this page, you get 50 results. `MULPD` and `MULSD` for the multiplication of doubles,
`FIMUL` for integer multiplication, ...

Those commands work on registers. Registers are memory slots which can contain a fixed number of bits (often 32 or 64, depending on which architecture your CPU uses), no matter what these bits represent.
Hence **the CPU instruction interprets the values of the registers in a different
way, but the values themselves don't have types.**

An example was given at [PyCon 2017 by Stuart Williams](https://youtu.be/oQca6eDcjA8?t=5m20s):

[image]

Comment: Note that this isn't strictly true: there are special-purpose registers that can't contain arbitrary values (for example, pointer registers that aren't just any address and don't allow arbitrary additions, or floating point registers where you can't store non-normalized values). But your answer is correct for *general-purpose* registers on *most* architectures.

Answer (score 2):

> ...that a particular program just tells the CPU to fetch the info from a specific address and the program defines how to treat it.

Exactly.  But RAM is not read "sequentially", and it stands for *Random Access Memory* which is exactly the opposite.

Besides knowing what a byte *is*, you don't even know if it's a *byte*, or a fragment of a larger item like a floating-point number.

I'd like to add to other answers by giving some specific examples.

Consider `01000001`.  The program might copy it from one place to another as part of a large parcel of data without any regard to its meaning.  But copying that to the address used by the text-mode video buffer will cause the letter `A` to show in some position on the screen.  The exact same action when the card is in a CGA graphics mode will display a red pixel and a blue pixel.

In a register, it could be the number 65 as an integer. Doing arithmetic to set the 32's bit could mean *anything* without context, but might specifically be changing a letter to lower case.

The 8086 CPU (still) has special instructions called [DAA](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref-daa.html)<sup>※</sup> that is used when the register holds 2 decimal digits, so if you just used that instruction you are interpreting it as two digits `41`.

Programs *crash* because a memory word is read thinking it is a pointer when something otherwise was stored there.

Using a debugger, inspecting memory, a *map* is used to guide the interpretation for display. Without this symbol information, a low-level debugger lets you specify: show this address as 16-bit words, show this address as long floating point, as strings... whatever.  Looking at a network packet dump or unknown file format, puzzling it out is a challenge.

That's a major source of power and flexibility in modern computer architecture: a memory cell can mean *anything*, data or instruction, implicit only in what it "means" to the program by what it does with the value and how that affects subsequent operations.  *meaning* is deeper than integer width: are these characters ... characters in ascii or ebcdic? Forming words in English or SQU product codes? The address to send to or the return address it came from?  The lowest level interpretation (logical bits; integer-like, signed or unsigned; float; bcd; pointer) is contextual at the instruction-set level, but you see that it's *all* context at some level: the *to* address is what it is because of the location it's printed on the envelope. It is contextual to the rules of the postman, not the CPU.  The context is one big continuum, with bits on one end of it.

---

※ Footnote: The DAA instruction is encoded as a byte `00100111`. So that byte is the aforenamed instruction if read in the instruction stream, and the digits `27` if interpreted as bcd digits, and 0x27 = 39 as an integer, which is the numeral *9* in ASCII, and part of the interrupt table (half of INT 13 2-byte address, used for BIOS service routines).

Answer (score 1):

The only way the computer knows that a memory location is an instruction is that a special-purpose register called the instruction pointer points to them at one point or another. If the instruction pointer points to a memory word, it is loaded as an instruction. Other than that, the computer has no way of knowing the difference between programs and other types of data.